Python function app how to terminate after a timer without harming other functions
I have inherited a collection of Python functions that are capable of deadlocking(this can happen at several places in the code), when that happens they seize all function time out on the Function app in Azure. This process then kills all other running function apps.
Obviously the deadlocking shouldn't be happening, nor should the process kill all other running function apps running on the same premium azure instance.
While we try to solve the underlying issues I would like to prevent one FA from killing the others if it deadlocks. As we know the deadlocks happen entirely within one function and no resource locks should be left if they get terminated.
As such I am looking for a way to terminate the execution of execution within a function app without harming the other executions on the same thread.
Our build script automatically transforms the FAExecutor via a package builder, so I altered that implementation into the following:
class FAExecutor(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def execute(self) -> None:
        raise NotImplementedError

    def execute_with_timeout(self) -> None:
        termination_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.timeout)
        termination_thread.start()
        self.execute()

    def timeout(self) -> None:
        timeout = 1200
        time.sleep(timeout)
        # Terminate the program
        os._exit()

class InfiteLoop(FAExecutor):

  def execute(self) -> None:
        logger = LoggerFactory.create_logger()

        while True:
            logger.warn("doing a looping")
            time.sleep(60)

This does result in the termination of the program within the function app. However if I execute this function twice with about 5 minutes between them then both executions are killed by this timeout. That is not the desired result.
Anybody know how to get the function to only kill the execution that sets the timeout rather then the entire environment? Azure threading is a bit opaque in this regard.

Below code worked for me with asyncio :
import asyncio as rith
import logging as ri_lg
import azure.functions as func


class Rith_Exec:
    async def test(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    async def test_time(self, timeout: int):
        try:
            await rith.wait_for(self.test(), timeout=timeout)
        except rith.TimeoutError:
            ri_lg.warning("Hello Rithwik Bojja, Function timeout and Cancelled.")

class Test_Infinite(Rith_Exec):
    async def test(self):
        rilg = ri_lg.getLogger(__name__)
        while True:
            rilg.warning("Looping Rithwik")
            await rith.sleep(60)

async def fun(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    ri = Test_Infinite()
    await ri.test_time(timeout=1200)
    return func.HttpResponse("Hello Rithwik, Function executed", status_code=200)

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    return rith.run(fun(req))

Output:
Local:

Portal:

